# JABSORB fixups in .NET

Tags: .net, json

Is there any built-in way to apply the "fixups" that JABSORB generates using json deserialization in .NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not.  I ended up doing it manually.  Fortunately I am using F# so it was easy.  If you look at the code to do this in javascript, It does it with similar ease (no need for reflection).

```
let applyFixups (json : JSON_RPC<JSONArrayList<_>>) =
    let applyFixup (items : array<_>) (fixup : array<array<obj>>) =
        let sourceIdx = fixup.[1].[1] :?> int
        let destIdx = fixup.[0].[1] :?> int
        let sourceProp = fixup.[1].[2] :?> string
        let destProp = fixup.[0].[2] :?> string
        let value = items.[sourceIdx].GetType().GetProperty(sourceProp).GetGetMethod().Invoke(items.[sourceIdx], Array.empty)
        items.[destIdx].GetType().GetProperty(destProp).GetSetMethod().Invoke(items.[destIdx], [|value|]) |> ignore
        ()
    if json.fixups <> null then
        let fu = json.fixups
        Seq.iter (applyFixup json.result.list) fu
    ()
```

The types for this are as follows...

```
[<DataContract>]
type JSON_RPC<'T> = {
    [<DataMember>]
    mutable fixups : array<array<array<obj>>>
    [<DataMember>]
    mutable id : int
    [<DataMember>]
    mutable result : 'T
}

[<DataContract>]
type JSONArrayList<'T> = {
    [<DataMember>]
    mutable javaClass: string
    [<DataMember>]
    mutable list: 'T array
}
```